# How many bytes does this array occupy in memory?

Tags: c++, pointers

I am working with c++, I saw this question in my book.
how many bytes will be occupied by this declaration?

```
float** p[5][10][2];
```

and there is no extra information about the memory of that machine?
is it possible to tell an explicit answer for this?

Comment: Sure: `sizeof(p)`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl is that dependent to specific machine? for example 200 is likely answer or not?

Comment: it does depend on the machine and `200` is unlikely to be the answer on any actually used machine (it could be the answer on some machines in the past and some custom CPUs). It is more likely 400 or or 800 depending on whether you got a 32 bit or a 64 bit build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the platforms.

In x86 platform, it occupies 5*10*2*4 bytes, because any pointer occupies 4 bytes in the platform.

So, it occupies  5*10*2*8 bytes in x64 platform.

Answer (score 3):

It's implementation dependent. So you'd find out with:

```
float** p[5][10][2];
std::cout << "sizeof(p) == " << sizeof(p) << '\n';
```

Comment: is it different number in different machines?

Comment: Yes, that is what "implementation dependent" means.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify. Here, you are declaring a 3D matrix which elements are pointers to something/float. Since you have 5x10x2 = 100 pointers, and pointers occupy 4b or 8b, the answer can be 400b or 800b.

Don't mess this with 100 * sizeof(float), because elements of matrix arent floats.